# Moving text to be to the left of plots in knitr bootstrap

Tags: css, r, knitr

I am using knitrBootstrap package within R to produce reports. For this particular audience I generally keep R code out of the report with echo=FALSE and this leaves a pretty large amount of white space to the right of plots with the default layout.

How do I go about editing the layout such that the plot images are right aligned and the text I write appears to the left of the plots rather than above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property `float: right` to make images float to the right, e.g.

````
```{r fig-a, out.extra='style="float: right"', echo=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
plot(x,y)
```
````

Example output:

[image: Right align plots in R Markdown]

Comment: This appears to work using knitr but is getting overridden by knitrBootstrap css. I appreciate your help.